# Static method to get DataSnapshot returns null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an Android app that uses Firebase database and I need DataSnapshot a lot in the app so I decided to make a helper method to get me the DataSnapshot and here how I managed to implement it inside a Helper class that I created:

```
static FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
static DatabaseReference playersReference =  database.getReference().child("players");
static DataSnapshot snapshot;

public static DataSnapshot getDataSnapshot(){

        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                snapshot = dataSnapshot;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        };

        playersReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);

        return snapshot;

    }
```

But whenever I try to use the method it returns null, any help?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how async listeners work.

Comment: Why do you say so?, not that listeners for single value are like no other listeners it doesn't (listen)  it executes only once.

Comment: `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` doesn't block and wait for a response. Your return statement is executed probably before the network request to Firebase even starts

Answer (score 1):

First, Create a separate helper class which breaks up the static calls to the database such as the following:

```
public class FirebaseDbRef {

    private static DatabaseReference ref; 

    private static DatabaseReference getFirebaseDatabase() {
        if (ref == null) 
            ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        return ref;
    }

    public static DatabaseReference getPlayerRef() {
        return getFirebaseDatabase().child("player");
    }

}
```

Then in your activity/fragment, call the method and add a listener to retrieve the snapshot:

```
FirebaseDbRef.getPlayerRef().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //USE SNAPSHOT
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            databaseError.getMessage();
        }
    });
```

Make sure your pathing is correct to access the proper snapshot. You can always Log to verify.

Comment: This is what I managed to implement it in the first place but I'm just trying to make my code more concise.

Answer (score 0):

The `getDataSnapshot()` does three things:

1. Creates a listener
2. Registers the listener
3. Returns `snapshot`

Note that none of these steps sets the value of `snapshot`. You are setting it in one of the listener's methods which is not called until after `getDataSnapshot()` returns.

Comment: So I have to take the body of the function inside an activity?.

Comment: @TheForgetten You need to pass the ValueEventListener as a parameter to your `getDataSnapshot()`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return something that hasn't been loaded yet. `onDataChange()` method is called asynchronous which means that is called even before you are getting the `DataSnapshot` object from the database. For more details you can see my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774).

If you want to use the `DataSnapshot` object outside `onDataChange()` method you need to create your own callback as explained at the end on that answer.